# How to horizontally fix a background using background-attachment but not vertically

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` (`#main`) that has been centred to the middle of the `body` element. `body` has a horizontally repeating background image and colour, aligned to the top-left of the element. `#main` has a fixed width, flexible height, and its own background image and colour.

What I'm trying to accomplish, as illustrated below, is to have the background image inside `#main` aligned with `body`'s background image. The two background images are going to be similar, so correct alignment is a necessity.

I attempted to use `background-attachment: fixed;` on `#main`'s background image, except that obviously results in the entire background image scrolling with the page; where as I'm trying to accomplish an effect where the background of `#main` is properly aligned with that of the `body`, but only repeats horizontally, and won't follow the user as they scroll vertically.

[Demonstration http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/2783/bgfixedexample.png](http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/2783/bgfixedexample.png)

(I tried to post this on [doctype](http://doctype.com/), except it won't accept my Google OpenID)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the properties background-position and background repeat

```
.myClass {
    background-image:url(myimg.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    background-position: -5px 5px; /* Any percentage or pixel value you want
     or you can use center top etc.*/
}
```

Play around with those css properties, I am confident you will achieve what you want.

Comment: I feel quite stupid in hindsight. Assuming that `#main` is horizontally centred, a background position of "`top center`" will align it properly. I hadn't noticed because in my test page, #main had an incorrect margin and wasn't centred.